# How does Windows decide which setting/template (Internet vs Datacenter) is applied to TCP connections?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, retransmit-timeout

In order to globally configure Minimum RTO; Delayed Ack Timeout; Congestion algo etc. under Windows 7 and above one is supposed to use network TCP templates.
To see those you can use Get-NetTCPSetting powershell cmdlet:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetTCPSetting

(...)

SettingName                   : Datacenter
MinRto(ms)                    : 20
InitialCongestionWindow(MSS)  : 4
CongestionProvider            : DCTCP
CwndRestart                   : True
DelayedAckTimeout(ms)         : 10
MemoryPressureProtection      : Enabled
AutoTuningLevelLocal          : Normal
AutoTuningLevelGroupPolicy    : NotConfigured
AutoTuningLevelEffective      : Local
EcnCapability                 : Enabled
Timestamps                    : Disabled
InitialRto(ms)                : 3000
ScalingHeuristics             : Disabled
DynamicPortRangeStartPort     : 49152
DynamicPortRangeNumberOfPorts : 16384

SettingName                   : Internet
MinRto(ms)                    : 300
InitialCongestionWindow(MSS)  : 4
CongestionProvider            : CTCP
CwndRestart                   : False
DelayedAckTimeout(ms)         : 50
MemoryPressureProtection      : Enabled
AutoTuningLevelLocal          : Normal
AutoTuningLevelGroupPolicy    : NotConfigured
AutoTuningLevelEffective      : Local
EcnCapability                 : Enabled
Timestamps                    : Disabled
InitialRto(ms)                : 3000
ScalingHeuristics             : Disabled
DynamicPortRangeStartPort     : 49152
DynamicPortRangeNumberOfPorts : 16384
```

In order to get individual connection and settings applied to them one can use Get-NetTCPConnection cmdlet:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetTCPConnection

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       --------------
(...)
192.168.75.69                       63220     192.168.75.66                       1433       Established Datacenter
192.168.75.69                       63208     192.168.75.61                       445        Established Internet
192.168.101.13                      63061     185.97.X.X                          20467      Established Datacenter
192.168.101.13                      63059     209.191.X.X                         18083      Established Internet
(...)
```

**How do I influence (or at least how is made) the choice of Internet vs Datacenter TCP settings?**
We have several low latency connections that we would like to treat with Datacentre settings (to speed up recovery from communication glitches), while still I do not want to blindly apply this to all connections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The settings profile applied to a given connection is based on the matching Transport Filter.  By default, there is a single filter that applies the `Automatic` settings profile to all connections, which is why yours are seemingly random.

```
PS C:\> Get-NetTransportFilter

SettingName       : Automatic
Protocol          : TCP
LocalPortStart    : 0
LocalPortEnd      : 65535
RemotePortStart   : 0
RemotePortEnd     : 65535
DestinationPrefix : *
```

The [New-NetTransportFilter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/hh826120(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet allows you to map connections to specific profiles based on either port numbers or IP address.

You can use something like

```
New-NetTransportFilter -SettingName Datacenter -DestinationPrefix 192.168.75.0/24
```

Or

```
New-NetTransportFilter -SettingName DataCenter -LocalPortStart 0 -LocalPortEnd 65536 -RemotePortStart 1433 -RemotePortEnd 1433
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on non-server versions of WIndows (eg Windows Enterprise)? We have some workstations with this same need, but the above command is blocked on non-servers. How do youy tell a workstation that some connection should be tuned using a different template (not "internet")?

Comment: Up until recently, I always ran Windows Server on my workstation machines, but now that I'm on Windows 10, I see what you mean.
`New-NetTransportFilter : This feature is available on servers only.`

Interesting also that the default filter sets the `Internet` profile instead of `Automatic` even though the others are defined.  I don't know of a way to get around that.

Comment: Struggling with this as well and posted https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/2061